# Scraping tables of various shapes

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data out of tables, which come in various shapes according to data entry in that table. For some reason, some tables (and hence data) are scrapped incorrectly.

```
require(data.table)
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
```

For this type of ID the scraping doesn't work:

```
 ur.l <- data.frame(A=c(1),B=c(36232475,36232475))
```

For other type ID it works:

```
ur.l <- data.frame(A=c(1),B=c(17053781,17054346))


scrape <- function(u) {
          tryCatch({
          tabs <- readHTMLTable(file.path("http://finstat.sk", u, 
                  "suvaha"),encoding='utf-8')
tab <- tabs[[which.max(sapply(tabs, function(x) nrow(x)))]]
data.table(tab)
}, error=function(e) cat())
}

urls <- as.character(ur.l[1:2,2]) 
res <- sapply(urls, scrape)

filter.null <- res[lapply(res,length)>0]

translit <- function(x) iconv(x, "UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", sub = "byte")
invisible(lapply(filter.null,function(x) x[,V1:=translit(V1)]))
```

Could be someone so kind and tell me how to adjust this so that any shape of table is scraped? For some ID it doesn't work...the error lies in the function `scrape()`. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Some explanation of context - what are you trying to do? - would be helpful here.

Comment: Does `res <- sapply(urls, scrape, simplify=FALSE)` give you what you expect?

Comment: That's it! If you would submit it as answer, I'm ready to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful when using `sapply` as it may give unexpected output. In this case you can

```
res <- sapply(urls, scrape, simplify=FALSE)
```

or use `lapply` instead.